# Select GPU for OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I have two GPUs connected to my archlinux system, an AMD and a nVidia. The screens are connected to the AMD one, and when I run an OpenGL application, it uses the AMD driver.

When using Vulkan, you can specify which driver to use, by specifying the VK_ICD_FILENAMES envvar.

Is is possible to specify which driver to use when using OpenGL? I would like to be able to select the nVidia card for some tasks.